# Equation of infinitesimal elements of absolute component and rotation angle component with right triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, approximation, angle, infinitesimals

I've drawn the below diagram.

[image]

$$  dx= a \cdot   \sec^{2}\left( \phi_{}  \right) d \phi_{}  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{?}$$

$$  x= a \tan \left( \phi_{}  \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{ok}  $$

$$  \phi_{} = \frac{\pi}{2} -\theta_{} ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{ok} $$

How do I deduce it?

My tries are as below.

$$  \frac{  dx  }{  d \phi_{}    } = a \sec ^{2} \left( \phi_{}  \right)  $$

$$  \frac{  dx  }{  d \phi_{}    } = \frac{  a  }{  \cos ^{2} \left(\phi_{} \right)   }   $$

$$  dx \cdot \cos ^{2} \left(\phi_{} \right)= a \cdot  d \phi_{}   $$

$$  dx \cdot \left( \cos\left(\phi_{} \right)  \right) ^{2} =a \cdot d \phi_{}  $$

$$  dx \cdot \left( \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta_{}  \right)  \right) ^{2} =a \cdot d \phi_{}  $$

$$  dx \cdot \left( \sin\left(\theta_{} \right)   \right) ^{2} =a \cdot d \phi_{}  $$

$$  dx \cdot \left( \frac{  a  }{  \sqrt{ x ^{2} + a ^{2}  }   }  \right) ^{2} = a \cdot  d \phi_{}  $$

$$  dx \cdot \left( \frac{  a ^{2}   }{  x ^{2} + a ^{2}   }  \right) = a \cdot d \phi_{} $$

$$  dx \cdot \frac{  a   }{  x ^{2} + a ^{2}   } = d \phi_{}  $$

I've been stucked from here.

Comment: It is not clear to me where you are starting, and what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Currently I can't get why $~dx= a \cdot   \sec^{2}\left( \phi_{}  \right) d \phi_{}~$ can be obtained.

Comment: OK, but what are you starting with? Are you starting with ${dx\over d\phi}=a\sec^2\phi\,d\phi$? If so, isn't $dx=a\sec^2\phi\,d\phi$ immediate?

Comment: I started to dig out the formula which I can understand transforming $~  \frac{  dx  }{  d \phi_{}    } = a \sec ^{2} \left( \phi_{}  \right)  ~$ . As that operation is succeeded , then just operating transformations backward can deduce $~  \frac{  dx  }{  d \phi_{}    } = a \sec ^{2} \left( \phi_{}  \right)  ~$

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you are saying. You seem to be happy with $x=a\tan\phi$. Why not just use it to compute $dx/d\phi$?

Comment: Ahhh. I missed that . I think I have to go to hospital.

Comment: I wish you a speedy recovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  x= a \tan \left( \phi_{}  \right) ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{ok}  $$

Just differentiate the formula with $~\phi~$ to obtain the stuff.